# MS Access validation rule

Tags: sql, database, validation, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to make the value of a field the first letter of a previous field but i cant figure it out, any help would be much appreciated.
Here is what I am looking to do;

```
If TNS_Type = "Printing" then
me="P"
ElseIf TNS_Type = "Sales" then
me="S"
ElseIf TNS_Type = "Repairs" then
me="R"
End If
```

me = a second input cell in the table.

TNS_Type = a previously completed cell in the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have and `UPDATE` statement using `LEFT` function something like this

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET me = LEFT(TNS_Type, 1)
```